# Send query to CFWheels selectTag form helper, or list with commas in string elements

Tags: forms, coldfusion, form-helpers, cfquery, cfwheels

I have a query that returns names in `<lastnamd>, <firstname>` format such as

```
<cfquery name="instructorSelectList" dataSource="GIRSReport">
    SELECT instructor_DBID,
           last_name + ', ' + first_name as instructor_name,
           hid
    FROM   instructors
    WHERE working_status = 'active'
    ORDER BY last_name, first_name  
</cfquery>
```

I want to use this query for a selectTag form helper. If I do:

```
    #selectTag
    (
        name="inst",
        id="program",
        options="#ValueList(instructorSelectList.instructor_name)#",
        valueField="#ValueLIst(instructorSelectList.instructor_DBID)#",
        display="#ValueList(instructorSelectList.instructor_name)#",
        selected="",
        label="HID",
        multiple="no",
        includeBlank="true",
        size=1,
        class="form-control",
        prepend="<br/>"
    )#
```

Then I get a list like `<lastname1>, <firstname1>, <lastname2>, <firstname2>, ...`

which is obviously not what I want.

If I just try to pass the `options` parameter a query, such as `options="#instructorSelectList.instructor_name#"`, the options don't fill properly.

The idea is to use a form helper equivalent to

```
<cfselect
    name="inst" 
    query="instructorSelectList" 
    queryPosition="below"
    value="instructor_DBID" 
    display="instructor_name" 
    label="HID" size=1
    class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
</cfselect>
```

Comment: Try using a different delimter in your valuelist().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're needing is to pass a query name to Options, without quotes (or in quotes surrounded by hashes) while the column names are quoted.

```
#selectTag
(
    name="inst",
    id="program",
    options=instructorSelectList,
    valueField="instructor_DBID",
    textField="instructor_name",
    selected="",
    label="HID",
    multiple="no",
    includeBlank="true",
    size=1,
    class="form-control",
    prepend="<br/>"
)#
```

**More Info:** [CFWheels selectTag() documentation](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/function/selecttag)